# How to build Net-SNMP library for use in iOS development?

Tags: ios, build, makefile, snmp, armv7

I need to use Net-SNMP in one of my iOS applications.
I want to use it as a library in Xcode.
How can I build the library?

I tried the following, but it did not work for me:

http://latenitesoft.blogspot.jp/2008/10/iphone-programming-tips-building-unix.html

I get the following error:

`configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

By the way, I'm targetting iOS 5 and 6.
Any help/leads will be greatly appreciated!

Some additional links I've looked at:
https://gist.github.com/j0sh/895945

Comment: Did you got any solution .? I am also trying the same . Please let me know .

Answer (score 3):

Here's a github project I found based on SNMP++:

https://github.com/Zchander/mobile-snmp-plusplus

Comment: I want to use Net-SNMP, and not SNMP++ because of some issues with SNMP++.

Comment: Fair enough. Just out of curiosity, what kind of issues?

Comment: Issues with using the library in other platforms.